# Hold application for x seconds

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sleep

I'm sorry if the title is confusing but I'm trying to record audio for 5 seconds and then run the close function.

I figured I just do it like this

```
StartFunction();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
StopFunction();
```

But that doesn't work since it will also not record while the thread is sleeping.

Then I figured maybe if I make a new thread, to do the sleep and stopfunction in. But when I do that and try to run the stopfunction it doesn't seem to stop anymore because it's trying to stop the recording in another thread if that makes sense.

So if anyone knows how I could fix this, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Timer`. There are three timers in .NET: `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Only the latter can assure you it will operate in the same thread. You need a Windows Application for that.

```
Class MyClass
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public MyClass()
    {
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 5000;
    }

    void Record()
    {
        StartFunction();
        timer.Start();        
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         timer.Stop();
         StopFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to do it in a different thread is correct (although you might want to look into [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), because they do the work of this for you).

I'm not a C#-er, but I believe what you're looking for to stop the recording is called synchronized methods. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188793.aspx) should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this:

- start recording
- start a timer (every 100ms could be ok) and set `DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now`
- when the timer event is raised check `(DateTime.Now - startTime)` and see if it is >= 5000ms: if so stop timer and stop recording

This gives you the possibility to set a decrementing timer on screen.
If you want to make it easier, you could run a timer with 5s delay and, on timer event, stop it and stop recording.

Comment: Or use a Stopwatch.. (Or at least DateTime.UtcNow, to avoid calculating the time zone)